# Trying to search mongo and send results to angular through express

Tags: angularjs, json, mongodb, express

I recently went through the [www.clementinejs.com](http://www.clementinejs.com) tutorial as I'm trying to learn the MEAN stack. I was able to complete it and understand most of it. However when i'm trying to repeat the process with mongoose and get slightly more data, I keep failing.

What i'm trying to do:

When page loads angular performs get request to '/api/entries' which searches mongo(via mongoose) and returns all docs in the collection, then load those docs into a div via angular ng-repeat.

If I insert dumby data into an object in the controller file I have no problem getting the data to show on the page, but when I try with the database I messed up somewhere. Even the angular curly brackets show up when I try to do it that way.

Here is my repo.

https://github.com/nickolaskg/journal

Should I just use mongo instead of mongoose? I'm not sure if i've set it up correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been stuck for days trying so many different approaches, at this point I have no doubt there is multiple problems in the code.

Comment: If the Angular curly braces show up, then some script error caused angular to fail to load. You will be more likely to find help with your issue if you narrow your question.  Use the browser console, find the error that has caused angular to fail to load, and ask about that section of code, rather than posting your entire repo.

Comment: my main question was not about the curly braces

Comment: true, your main question is about why your program doesn't work.  The curly braces are indicating that there is an error and that's why your code doesn't work.  Post the error, rather than asking people to find the error and fix it for you.

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way.  I'm sure that there is a solution to your issue, and it's definitely possible to work through your errors to find a solution.  Asking you to post the error is an attempt to help you understand *how* to solve your issue, rather than just posting blind changes.  Though now it seems that you have other errors, which can be frustrating.  Don't give up, I'm sure a solution can present itself.  To your initial question, there isn't any reason that mongoose would cause angular issues....

Answer (score 0):

```
Entry.get(function(result){
  $scope.entries = result;
})
```

`get()` expects single object in the response.

Please read `$resource`'s [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Use:

1. `Entry.query({field1: 'criterion'})` for queries and **multiple** resources.
2. `Entry.get({_id: 'someid'})` for a **single** resource.
3. `Entry.save({my: 'properties'})` for **saving** existing resource or **creating** a new resource.
4. `Entry.delete({_id: 'someid'})` for deleting a **single** resource.

Also next time please post relevant code (IE your `$resource` calls) directly.